# Read big firebase json file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a big firebase json file and I want to read it using a stream (line by line) to reduce load on memory. I want to perform some processing to each key properties step by step.
This is a sample json format:

```
{
  "obj1": {
    "OS": {
      "android": true
    },
    "firstVisitDate": "23-Jun-2022 03:06",
    "numberOfVisits": 1,
    "numberOfVisitsCommulative": {
      "202206": 1
    }
  },
  "obj2": {
    "firstVisitDate": "01-May-2021 02:06 PM",
    "lastVisitDate": "01-May-2021 02:06 PM",
    "numberOfVisits": 1
  }
}
```

I want to get the first obj1 and process it. Then read obj2 and process it.
I am using NodeJS

Comment: Are you really experiencing a bottleneck reading the file? Because what you ask will prove to be complicated, as streams usually read in chunks of a certain size rather than line by line. Also I don't see how you would be able to decode the json when partially loaded, as it will be invalid, you'll have to trim it, possibly detect braces matchings, a lot of work

Comment: Yes, i thought there would be other way around to read big data json files,

Comment: Have you tried [searching npm for *streaming json*](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=streaming%20json)?

Comment: Maybe there are libraries that can do it that I haven't heard of, if memory is really an issue, can't you export you firebase data to multiple files?

Comment: That is the problem, I have a document of 500mb, i can not break it and export, may be i do no how to so, or there is not functionality on firebase to run query